# Distribute argument parameter pack to invoke two functors

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm trying to invoke two functional objects through one given argument pack (`typename Args... args`), an integer parameter is provided to mark the border where i need to split the pack to invoke both functional objects correctly.

Consider the following example:

```
Args... = <int, int, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>
unsigned Bounds = 2;

functor Foo (left) and Bar (right)

// Foo is invoked with <int, int>
// Bar is invoked with <std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>

// An evaluator template class is invoked to merge the result of both,
// for example with an add (operator+) operation
```

My idea was to create two integer sequences and use `std::get` to invoke both functional objects at once with those two integer sequences:

```
// Sequence creator
template<unsigned Position, unsigned Count, unsigned... Pack>
struct make_sequence
    : std::conditional<
        Count == 0,
        std::common_type<sequence<Pack...>>,
        make_sequence<Position + 1, Count - 1, Pack..., Position>
    >::type { };

// Create a sequence from inclusive from to exclusive to
template<unsigned InclusiveFrom, unsigned ExclusiveTo>
using make_sequence_from_to_t = typename make_sequence<
    InclusiveFrom,
    (ExclusiveTo <= InclusiveFrom) ? 0U : (ExclusiveTo - InclusiveFrom)
>::type;

template<typename LeftType, typename RightType, unsigned Bounds, typename Evaluator>
class distribute_functor
{
    LeftType left_;
    RightType right_;

    template<unsigned... LeftSeq, unsigned... RightSeq, typename... Args>
    auto internal_invoke(sequence<LeftSeq...>, sequence<RightSeq...>, Args... args)
    {
        return Evaluator::evaluate(left_(std::get<LeftSeq>(args)...),
//                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^~~^^^^~~~~~
//                                 error C3528: 'LeftSeq': the number of
//                                 elements in this pack expansion does not
//                                 match the number of elements in 'args'
                                   right_(std::get<RightSeq>(args)...));
    }

public:
    template<typename Left, typename Right>
    distribute_functor(Left left, Right right)
        : left_(std::forward<Left>(left)), right_(std::forward<Right>(right)) { }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator() (Args... args)
    {
        return internal_invoke(make_sequence_from_to_t<0, Bounds>{},
                               make_sequence_from_to_t<Bounds, sizeof...(Args)>{},
                               std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

However the VisualStudio 14 compiler complains about a mismatch between the count of parameters in the arguments pack and in the sequence:

> error C3528: 'LeftSeq': the number of elements in this pack expansion does not match the number of elements in 'args'

*There is still the way to use `std::tuple` for the functor invocation which i don't prefer.*

**Is there another or better way to partial invoke two functional objects in one step from one argument pack?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::get` cannot be used this way.

You should write `internal_invoke` like this:

```
template<unsigned... LeftSeq, unsigned... RightSeq, typename ArgsAsTuple>
auto internal_invoke(sequence<LeftSeq...>, sequence<RightSeq...>,ArgsAsTuple&& args) const
{
  return Evaluator::evaluate(left_(std::get<LeftSeq>(args)...),
                             right_(std::get<RightSeq>(args)...));
}
```

And invoke it with `forward_as_tuple`:

```
return internal_invoke(make_sequence_from_to_t<0, Bounds>{},
                       make_sequence_from_to_t<Bounds, sizeof...(Args)>{},
                       std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
```

**Explanation:**

Two paramter packs of different arity must be expanded separately. When you write `std::get<LeftSeq>(args)...`, you try to expand together packs of different arity. This cannot be done. You should have wrote `std::get<LeftSeq>(args... /* 1st expand/) ... /* 2nd expand */`. This is syntactically correct but does not match `std::get` API. [std::forward_as_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) is there to help you and has been written precisely for those types of use cases.

**Edit:**

If you want to avoid the tuple, then you must write your own version of `std::get` to match your need, provided you expand the parameters correctly as I explained above.

Comment: Seems like `std::forward_as_tuple` fits my needs... it's completely optimized out on recent compilers which means the theoretical overhead is nonexistent.